# What's "כי אתא פלוני אמר פלוני"?

Tags: words, eretz-yisrael, travel, talmud-bavli, quotations

The phrase "‫כי אתא [name] אמר [name],‏ [statement]‏‬‬" appears many times in the *Bavli*. For example,

- [*Rosh Hashana* 35:1](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1354): כי אתא רבין אמר רבי יעקב בר אידי אמר רבי שמעון חסידא לא פטר רבן גמליאל אלא עם שבשדות
- [*Shabas* 52:1](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=226): כי אתא רב דימי אמר ר׳ חנינא מולאות של בית רבי יוצאות באפסריהן בשבת
- [*Avoda Zara* 73:1](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4121): כי אתא רב דימי א״ר יוחנן המערה יין נסך מחבית לבור אפילו כל היום כולו ראשון ראשון בטל

I've always understand that it means — in the last quotation, for example — "when *R. Dimi* came [from Israel], he said that *R. Yochanan* said 'one who pours…'". But that seems to be missing an "אמר": it should logically be "כי אתא רב דימי א״ר יוחנן אמר המערה…‏" or perhaps "כי אתא רב דימי אמר א״ר יוחנן המערה…‏" or even "כי אתא אמר רב דימי א״ר יוחנן המערה…‏". So what is the meaning of the phrase, and how does that meaning fit the words?

Comment: I think it's just an [elliptical construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29), and the meaning is as you suggest. There are other times in the Talmud where the word אמר is dropped, aside from just כי אתא statements (e.g. [*P'sachim* 106b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=106b&format=text), where what should be ואמר רבה אמר רב נחמן turns into ורבה אמר רב נחמן).